# Selenium Element Not Clickable

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

After clicking a link on a website, the URL does not change, but a popup will load on the screen with elements that I have only been able to access after running `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`
I have only been able to use the javascript executor to access the element using `await driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('viewDevice').click()");`
I receive the following error after that line(Scroll to the right to view whole error)

The HTML for the entire page is quite large, So I have attached a screenshot showing the condensed HTML for the Main Body tag of the markdown. You can see that when hovered over the body tag that there is an element blocking the entire screen. So the question seems to be, how can I click an element that is underneath a transparent element on top of the entire screen? Thanks for any help! This has been bugging me for days!

```
     (node:19397) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error:

                    Element <a ng-if="isDTTModalViewOn" tabindex="0" ng-click="dttDialog()"
            ddh-modal="" window-class="modal-fullscreen light-theme" size-class="" 
        modal-ok="ok()" modal-cancel="cancel()" href="javascript:void(0);" 
    class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">...</a> is not clickable at point (413, 988). 
Other element would receive the click: <div class="fsrModalBackdrop fsrAbandonButton" id="fsrFullScreenContainer" data-isbackdrop="true">...</div>
```

> Below is the html for the element I am trying to access that is being blocked

```
<div class="top-5px float-left" style="width: 405px;">
        <div class="MyBillWDBg298" id="viewDevice">
            <div class="">
                <a role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="viewDeviceBox" class="btnimg block" tabindex="0" style="text-decoration: none !important;" name="View Usage for">
                    <div style="min-height:36px; " class="MyBillWDBg298 ">

                                <p class="PadTop10 PadBot5 PadLeft10 botMar0 deviceName ellipsis PadRight10">



name | phone#
                                </p>


                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="viewDeviceBox" role="group" aria-label="Device info" style="position: absolute; display: none;" class="z1000WithoutErrorMsg ">
                <div style="width: 298px;" class="box no-top-round ">
                    <dl class="MarLeft10 MarTop15 botMar15">

                            <dd class="botMar10 MarRight10 ">
                                <span class="block" style="width: 230px;"><a class="wt_Body" linkname="Device DropDown_#" name="Tyler Fox" href="#" onclick="doUsageDeviceContent( 'phone#' ); DTMReportingHelper.triggerLinkClickReporting(this);">


name | #
                                </a></span>
                            </dd>


                            <dd class="botMar10 MarRight10 ">
                                <span class="block" style="width: 230px;"><a class="wt_Body" linkname="Device DropDown_#" name="name" href="#" onclick="doUsageDeviceContent( '#' ); DTMReportingHelper.triggerLinkClickReporting(this);">


name | phone#
                                </a></span>
                            </dd>


                            <dd class="botMar10 MarRight10  orangeCheck ">
                                <span class="block" style="width: 230px;"><a class="wt_Body" linkname="Device DropDown_phone#" name="users name" href="#" onclick="doUsageDeviceContent( 'phone#' ); DTMReportingHelper.triggerLinkClickReporting(this);">


name | phone#
                                </a></span>
                            </dd>


                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

[image: Element I am trying to access]

[image: Element blocking elements underneath]

Comment: post the markup.  The error means that there is something on top of the item you are trying to click.

Comment: I found what is blocking the page. There is an element on top of the entire page. Getting the HTML now. thanks

Comment: @pcalkins the HTML for the entire page is too large to post. I have added the html for the element I am trying to access and a screenshot showing inspecting the element html that is blocking the page. If there is anything else you need I will get it. This is driving me mad! Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if there are any iframes on the page.  Also, when you say a popup appears, is that just a DIV, or is there actually another window/tab appearing?  It looks like the item you are clicking is designed to open a popup and then process the click.  That part is hard to tell without seeing the scripts used.  It may open a new tab, OR change the current tab's url and/or content, and then open a second tab for the page. (a "popunder")  In any case you should generate the click on the object which is on top first.  Then generate a 2nd click for the element you want in the correct tab.

Comment: To explain further, the page is relying on the event "bubbling up" the DOM, but since Selenium will throw this error if you try to click the element, it won't happen.  The overlay will probably collapse/hide/remove itself after it receives a click.  Depending on the scripts used the element's click event may also check to see that the popup/popunder has loaded before executing the function associated with the click.  (Passing a variable... something like "adloaded=true"...)

Comment: The page does have iframe tags. It is just a DIV. but it has a button that you can use to close it. No new tab or window is opened. The element I'm trying to click is a popdown menu that allows the user to select the phone number that they want to view.

Comment: Would this code click the body and collapse it? I tried this but it didn't seem to change anything. await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//html")).click();

Comment: The div that is overlaying is shown in your exception: "<div class="fsrModalBackdrop fsrAbandonButton" id="fsrFullScreenContainer" data-isbackdrop="true">...</div>"

Answer (score 0):

The element I was trying to click was contained within an iframe. By figuring out the name of the iframe, in this case it was "frame_a" I was able to use the switch frame function to access it.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe_a");
```

After switching the frame I was able to click the element using the javascript executor.